# How can I tell what row has been inserted into Firebird db via JSP

Tags: jsp, insert, firebird

I am using executeUpdate(query) to insert a row into a Firebird database table and while this works all it tells me is whether it has worked or not.

What I need to know is WHAT row was inserted i.e. when the record is inserted a unique primary key and I need to know this ID so that it can be referred to in later statements.

Is this possible to do and if so how?

Thanks

Neil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`RETURNING` clause](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-insert-returning) of the [`INSERT` statement](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-insert), introduced in Firebird 2.0:

```
INSERT INTO ... RETURNING PKFieldName
```

Answer (score 2):

I just mailed this in response to your mail to the Firebird-Java mailinglist:

Jaybird 2.2 will add support for retrieval of the generated key using getGeneratedKeys() (in combination with the specific execute methods that are defined in JDBC to support this functionality).

That functionality is however not available in Jaybird 2.1.6 IIRC, but - with Firebird 2.0 or higher - you can use `INSERT ... RETURNING <your-primary-key-field>` and execute that as a query (eg executeQuery) instead of an update. The returned resultset will then include the primary key that was generated (which is almost identical to what Jaybird 2.2 will do for the getGeneratedKeys() functionality).